# Metathese in der Infinitivendung - "hab ich eben gefundne"

Tags: dialect, spoken-language, evolution

Manchmal höre ich *-ne* anstelle von inf. *-(e)n*. Das hatte ich bisher als Sächsisch gezählt, wegen eines Schulfreunds. Dessen Vater aus Dresden spricht aber keinen starken Dialekt, er selbst eigentlich gar nicht.

Bei Ricarda Lang (die Grünen), kann man es manchmal ebenso hören. Die ist jedoch geborene Baden-Würtembergerin. Kürzlich habe ich es von einem Österreicher gehört (Wer zündete die BVB-Bombe; Zeitmarke [ca. 8:53](https://www.youtube.de/watch?v=_0VsuDkwMug&t=520)).

Jetzt will ich es ganz genau wissen. Phonetik und Phonologie sind ja zwei unterschiedliche Paar Schuhe. Vielleicht ist es nur der Auslaut des stimmhaften Konsonanten oder doch historisch begründet.

Wie wird das Problem eindeutig beschrieben—lässt sich die Distribution genauer eingrenzen, um die Ursachen zu ermitteln?

Comment: Wo hast du gelesen, dass es in Österreich sächsische Dialekte gibt? Da würde mich eine Quellenangabe interessieren. Deine Fragen sind übrigens besser als deine Antworten (+1 von mir).

Comment: Da war nur der Titel "Siebenbürgisch-Sächsisches Wörterbuch" um Siebenbürgen mit Österreich und Böhmen zu verbinden. Doch das "entstammt vermutlich dem lateinischen Stereotyp jener Zeit *Saxones* für westliche (überwiegend deutsche) Siedler." (de.WP) Das ändert nichts an meinem Bezug zu Dresden, nur die Wortwahl war wohl fehlgeleitet.

Comment: Ein "Siebenbürgisch-Sächsisches Wörterbuch" ist kein Wörterbuch, das beim Übersetzen zwischen Siebenbürgisch und Sächsisch hilft, sondern es ist ein Wörterbuch über die Sprache der [Siebenbürger Sachsen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siebenbürger_Sachsen). Das sind Menschen, deren Vorfahrenaus Sachsen waren, die in Siebenbürgen eingewandert sind. Siebenbürgen, wo Glaubensfreiheit herrschte, gehörte aber lange Zeit zu Österreich. Daher siedelten sich dort auch viele Protestanten aus dem katholischen österreichischen Kernland an, die sich dann mit den Sachsen vermischten.

Comment: Österreich hat aber im 1. Weltkrieg große Teile seines Staatsgebiets verloren, darunter auch Siebenbürgen, und in dem kleinen Restgebiet, das von Österreich übrig geblieben ist, gibt es seitdem keine sächsisch sprechende Volksgruppe mehr. Auf österreichischem Boden gibt es nur vereinzelte Zuwanderer aus Sachsen, diese gelten aber nicht als autochtone Österreicher.

Answer (score 4):

Ein besonders markantes Beispiel ist Gerald Klug, der vom 11. März 2013 bis zum 26. Jänner 2016 österreichischer Verteidigungsminister war. Von ihm stammt nicht nur das Adjektiv *situationselastisch,* ([Youtube](https://youtu.be/etPpyTtQ4_Q), 14 Sekunden lang) das 2014 zum österreichische Wort des Jahres gekürt wurde, sondern er war auch sehr bekannt für seine sonderbare Art, das Wort *»Soldaten«* auszusprechen. Das betraf bei ihm aber alle Wörter, die auf *-en* enden. Hier ist ein 14-Sekunden-Ausschnitt aus einer Ansprache an eine Gruppe österreichischer Soldaten:

[Gerald Klug - "Soldatna"](https://youtu.be/wenrVEOsDkI):

> Umso wichtiger ist es, dass wir gerade in diesen **Zeitna** auf professionell ausgebildete **Soldatna,** flexibel einsetzbare **Soldatna,** wie Sie es sind, zurückgreifen können.

<sub>Die Ausspracheversion von Gerald Klug ist inzwischen Teil des österreichischen Kulturguts, und so brachte 2021 die Wiener Band [Freunde Schöner](http://www.freundeschoener.at) den Song [Soldatna](https://youtu.be/pk9X0cMvueM) auf den Markt. Sie singen das ganze Lied im besten Hochdeutsch. (Wenn ich es nicht besser wüsste, und raten müsste von wem das Lied ist, hätte ich auf Sportfreunde Stiller getippt.) Lediglich im Refrain (das erste Mal bei ca. 1:03 und stark gehäuft von ca. 2:20 bis 2:50) wird das Wort *Soldaten* so ausgesprochen, wie es Gerald Klug 2013-2016 vorgemacht hat. (Gleich nach *Soldtna* kommt jedes Mal *Habt Achtna*, aber nur wegen des Reims.)</sub>

#### Warum ist das so?

Gerald Groß wurde 1968 (also nur 3 Jahre nach mir) in Graz (Hauptstatt des Bundeslandes Steiermark) geboren, und das ist auch meine Geburtsstadt. Ich kenne Gerald Groß zwar nicht persönlich, aber ich kenne viele andere Steirer (so nennt man die Bewohner der Steiermark) die zwischen 1950 und 1980 geboren wurden, und darunter sind zwar nicht viele, aber doch einige, die so sprechen wie Gerald Groß. Unter anderem hatte ich eine Zeit lang einen Chef, der auch so sprach. Daher kam mir, als ich Groß das erste Mal hörte, seine Sprechweise zwar provinziell, aber nicht besonders auffällig vor.

Der größte Teil der Steiermark liegt in dem Gebiet, in dem Mittelbairisch (auch Donaubairisch genannt) gesprochen wird. Die Weststeiermark (die nicht im Westen, sondern im Süden liegt)<sup>1</sup> gehört aber zum Süd- oder Alpenbairischen Sprachgebiet. Graz liegt genau an der Grenze zwischen den beiden Dialekt-Gebieten. In beiden Varianten der Bairischen Dialekte ist es üblich, in Endsilben, die auf *-en* enden, den Vokal wegzulassen und stattdessen den Konsonanten n zu vokalisieren, so wie das bei den meisten Wörtern in der hochdeutschen Alltagssprache im gesamten Sprachraum gemacht wird.

Wenn man aber das betroffene Wort besonders deutlich aussprechen möchte, spricht man in der standarddeutschen Aussprache den Vokal doch aus und reduziert dafür die Vokalisierung des n. So wird aus [zeːn] bzw. österreichisch [seːn] für das Wort *»sehen«* bei Hervorhebung [ˈzeːən] oder gar [ˈzeːhən] (bzw. in Österreich: [ˈseːən] oder [ˈseːhən]). Dort, wo ich aufgewachsen bin (Graz und Umgebung) gibt es aber viele Dialektsprecher, die diesen Aussprachewandel bei Hervorhebung nicht machen. Da wird einfach versucht, das vokalisierte [n] stärker zu betonen. Wenn sich dann am Ende des Konsonanten [n] die Zunge von den Vorderzähnen bzw. dem vorderen Gaumen löst, während aber der Stimmapparat noch Klang produziert, wird daraus ein Schwa-Laut, den man normalerweise am Ende von *einer* oder *jeder* hört ([ɐ]). Beide Effekte zusammen (Nichtsprechen des eigentlich zu sprechenden Vokals vor dem [n] und Herausrutschen eines eigentlich nicht zum Wort gehörenden Vokals danach) haben zur Folge, dass es für Zuhörer so wirkt, als würden diese Sprecher die Reihenfolge von Vokal und Konsonant verwechseln. Tatsächlich ist es aber ein anderer Vokal (aus [ən] wird nicht [nə] sondern [nɐ]).

Das ist eigentlich eine schlampige und fehlerhafte Aussprache, aber wenn sie von anderen kommentarlos toleriert wird, und wenn man noch dazu dieselbe Aussprache auch von andren Menschen in der Umgebung hört, behalten sie manche Menschen eben bei.

---

**Sächsisch in Österreich?**
Nein. In Österreich sprechen nur einige deutsche Immigranten und Touristen Sächsisch. In Vorarlberg (ganz im Westen des Bundesgebietes) spricht man allemannische Dialekte, sonst überall bairische.

---

<sup>1</sup> **Off-Topic** (Warum ist die Weststeiermark nicht im Westen der Steiermark?)
Bevor die Steiermark ein Teil der Habsburger-Monarchie wurde, war sie ein Herzogtum und erstreckte sich viel weiter in den Süden als heute. Der Teil, der heute in Slowenien liegt und in dem die Bevölkerung auch schon in der Monarchie slowenisch gesprochen hat (aber Amtssprache Deutsch), heißt *Untersteiermark* und war in der Monarchie die südliche der drei Verwaltungszonen der Steiermark. (In der steirische Landeshymne singen wir auch heute noch vom *»Wendenland im Tal der Sav'«.*) Der alpine Teil nördlich der Linie, die von den Flüssen Mur und Mürz gebildet wird, ist die *Obersteiermark,* sie war die nördliche Verwaltungsregion. Die Fläche der Obersteiermark macht gut 60% der Fläche der heutigen Steiermark aus. Dazwischen liegt als dritte ehemalige Verwaltungszone die bevölkerungsreiche Mittelsteiermark mit der Hauptstadt Graz im Zentrum. Die Mittelsteiermark wird durch die Mur, die dort von Norden nach Süden fließt, in 2 Hälften geteilt, die man West- und Ost-Steiermark nennt. Als 1919 die Monarchie zu Ende ging und die Untersteiermark ein Teil des neuen Königreichs Jugoslawien wurde, wurden auch die Verwaltungszonen aufgelöst. Der name *Obersteiermark* blieb, aber der Begriff *Mittelsteiermark* wurde nicht mehr verwendet. Wegen der feinen Unterschiede im Dialekt waren aber die Weststeirer und die Oststeirer leicht auseinanderzuhalten, daher blieben die Bezeichnungen Weststeiermark und Oststeiermark weiterhin in Verwendung. Die folgende Karte zeigt die Lage der Regionen: https://hubert.schoelnast.at/pics/Steiermark.png

Answer (score 2):

In bairischen Dialekten in Österreich ergibt sich die "Metathese" nur sekundär. Zugrunde liegt immer eine Silbe mit elidiertem Schwa, in der das [n] silbisch wird. Das ist sozusagen "Standard", und obligatorisch: [gfʊndn̩].  Darüber hinaus tendieren manche Specher, in manchen Dialekten, manchmal dazu, ein Schwa dahinter einzufügen.  Das passiert vor allem in Kontexten, in denen versucht wird, standardnah zu sprechen: der Herr in deinem Video sagt zB. [gefʊndnə], was sicher nicht seiner "normalen" aussprache entspricht (sondern er sich wahrscheinlich bewusst an einen deutschen Interviewer richtet).  Ich tippe hier also auf Hyperkorrektur; das muss aber nicht immer der Fall sein.

Und sächsische Dialekte gibt es nicht in Österreich (abgesehen von Einwanderern).  Neben bairisch kommt nur allemannisch in und um Vorarlberg vor, das vielleicht manche daran erinnern könnte.

Comment: Ist Hyperkorrektur wirklich zutreffend? Das würde in etwa heißen, es sei in eingeschränktem Maße irgendwo korrekt, nixht dass es in jedem Fall nur teilweise korrekt ist (weil das schwerer zu quantifizieren ist). Ich verstehe den Beitrag so, falls *e*  im Dialekt korrekt ist, tritt es unwillkürlich an standarliches n̩, um dem Sprachgefühl zu genügen. Aber ob das verallgemeinert werden kann oder nur als phonetisches Phänomen am Satzende erscheint (woher es verallgemeinert werden könnte), und wo, bleibt in dieser Antwort offen. ...

Comment: … Außerdem lässt sich anhand der Antwort weder ausschließen noch bestätigen, ob es in einigen Fällen als Archaismus einer ansonsten verloren gegangen Endung betrachtet werden könnte (die, sofern diese verallgemeinert wurde, doch wieder als Hyperkorrektur betrachtet werden könnte). Ich denke da z.B. spontan an *-ing*, weil dessen Herkunft ungewiss ist und *g* > *a* im Norden vorkommen kann.